# Test Runner Bin Path for executing via cmd on TFS (Opencover)

Tags: tfs, mstest, sonarqube, sonar-runner, opencover

I'm trying to execute OpenCover to get code coverage results integrated with TFS build. This results are sent to SonarQube (via sonar-runner, that is included in the build template as an activity). I have two TFS Servers, One Controller and several agents in both servers. We use tags in the agents, so the .Net builds can be executed in any agent with matching tags.

To integrate OpenCover, i've created a cmd file in a project and added to source control. The details are in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26651450/1764875

But in TFS Servers, the path for MSTest is not the same, and i don't want to add some logic to choose a path depending on the build server.

And also other .Net projects are using other test runners (XUnit, NUnit) that are integrated in projects and run in that TFS Servers ok.

To run OpenCover, I need the path to the correct Test Runner Binary. My question is:

**- Is there any way to get this path in Build time (in the Build definition, using some variable for example)?**

Any advise will be welcome!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible for the moment. There's currently a strong requirement which is to run the SonarQube analysis at the same place where the reports to reuse were generated.

Feel free to come on the user mailing list to discuss this and share your user experience, this may trigger some actions on SonarQube side.

Comment: Fabrice, thanks for your feedback! But... I'm not sure that i'm understanding you... My concern is about generating OpenCover Report on TFS. How is this related with that?

Comment: Ho, sorry, I read the question too fast. But this has nothing to do with SonarQube then, right?

Comment: Hmmm... The final purpose is to have code coverage information in sonarqube. But first,in the described scenario, it has to be generated in an automated build based on TFS. If it is some way to get code coverage directly on sonar without third party tools (reports) it would be great! Anyway, sending the report to sonarqube is not currently an issue except for the case when the report is not generated and sonar-runner fails because can't find it...