# How to use code coverage tools in continuous build integration of TFS 2013?

Tags: tfs, code-coverage, opencover

I am using the TFS 2013\VS 2013 professional editions for continuous build. Am looking to use an open source tool like OpenCover for code coverage. I have no prior experience in code coverage tools. I installed the OpenCover UI from Nuget but not sure how to include Codecoverage in integrated build in TFS.  Getting "No Code Coverage Results" when the build runs.

I enabled code coverage under Automated tests node in build definition.

Any suggestion on how to implement code coverage in TFS\VS 2013 Profession edition would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean **Enabled Code Coverage** in the build definition just like below screeshot.

[image]

This is VS build-in code coverage, according to the [Compare VS offerings](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/) site, only **Visual Studio Enterprise** has Code Coverage feature, so if you use TFS for your CI build and want to use the built-in code coverage feature, installing VS Enterprise on your build agent machine is required.

---

If you want to integrate  *OpenCover* with TFS XAML build, you need to customize your build process template, add a custom activity in the build definition to trigger the opencover command for generating the report.

> - Created a RunCoverage.cmd at the root of my source folder
> - Installed / copied in TFS Servers the Opencover binaries and added into Path(must restart TFS Services to enable TFS to see it).
> - Created a new actitivity in the build definition, that is, editing the build template (before sonar execution activity) to run the cmd:
>
>   - [Running command line statements from TFS custom activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770333/running-command-line-statements-from-tfs-custom-activity)
>   - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg265783.aspx
>
> There is the cmd contents:
>
> ```
> @REM @echo suppresses command line. ^ is line continuation character
> @ECHO Executing OpenCover...
> OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user ^
> -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" ^
> -targetargs:"/testcontainer:%~dp0test.dll /usestderr /resultsfile:%~dp0MSTestsResults.trx" ^
> -output:%~dp0opencovertests.xml
> ```

More details please refer *Naim Raja Díaz*'s answer in this similar question:[Integration of OpenCover with TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533735/integration-of-opencover-with-tfs)